# Select where Row has '/' in 4th location

Tags: sql, select, position, where-clause

I'm working on a query to select from my location row all entries that have a '/' in the 4th position.
I've tried doing stuff like

```
WHERE location LIKE '___/'
```

etc, but I'm not sure what I could or should be using.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL server then this will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
where  SUBSTRING(location,4,1) = '/'
```

Comment: Also, for Oracle. Same function

Answer (score 2):

You may try using this

```
WHERE SUBSTRING ( location ,4 , 1 ) = '/'
```

Comment: My vote put your reputation into 3 digits.  You owe me a beer.